# Disable session_start(); on landing page only?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

*I've searched SO before but wasn't able to fix my issue*

I have my session parameters included in my header. 
And this header is included in all my pages. 
Works great except for the landing page (where users register or log in): I get the infamous `Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent` error.

Is there a way I could use `disable session_start();` on the landing page only without having to remove the whole header ?

If not, what other options should I look into ?

**EDIT:**

Here's my session parameters at the top of my header file:

```
session_start();
$lifetime=5000000;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
```

**This error doesn't show in development. Only in production.**

Comment: rather than disabling something you already enabled, can you not re-structure some code - ie your includes/libraries/functions/includes/etc? What is causing this error in the "landing" page? And can you show some code?

Comment: @James if i cannot fix my issue, then yes, i will re-structure some code but I'm trying to avoid this option for now.

Comment: fair enough, I see why that's your preferred outcome. I think you need to find what is causing this error in the "landing" page, rather than try to disable sessions. This will return your desired outcome. Can you show code from the landing page?

Comment: i dont think you are targeting the right problem. i've had this problem also in production and the whole problem was a single line of session setting attempt, you see! if a page sends a header you cannot send a another because the server does request one at a time, i doesnt mean you cant have multiple headers sent, but you have multiple SAME headers, meaning some where in your code you are redirecting,, look for `header()` functions that try to send headers based on if statements or whatever, also look to see if you dont have a white space between `<?php` and `session_start()`

Comment: is like `header('Location: lcalala1.php'); if (1=1){ header('Location: lalala.php'); }` you see? they were already sent

Comment: @WeTheBrains I wish I could upvote you! Indeed, i fixed the issue by removing an empty line before session_start() ! Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have any problem using `session_start()` in the landing page . You would just need to make sure your header script is included at the top of the page so that nothing else is sent to be browser before the call to `session_start()` . It is because :

> **Note** : To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Above note is copied from : http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

May be you can do this : Check if header are already sent . If headers are already sent avoid calling `session_start()` .

This page might help you in that direction : [How to check if Headers already been sent in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820639/how-to-check-if-headers-already-been-sent-in-php)

You would still need to find the reason for the issue and would need to fix it but for time being code along this lines should help :

```
if( ! headers_sent() )
{
    session_start();
    $lifetime=5000000;
    session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, session_start() is at the top of my header file which is included in my landing page. So nothing else is being sent to the browser before. See my edited question.

Comment: well, this is good general advice on `session_start()` but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your comment . Thanks for accepting . . .

Answer (score 0):

There may be some error/warnings in your page those sent to browser before further execution.
To make continue execution you can write ob_start in the header page or in first landing page.